Git clone, modify and build for vite install (excalidraw)
I am new to JS development and have made a clone of a github repo and made local changes that I need to that clone. I now want to use the clone in my project, which is packaged with vite. How do I use the local clone with my changes as a dependency in my main project?
I have tried:

Adding the local path of my clone as a dependency in my package.json
Reuploading the fork to github and adding the github repo as a dependency in package.json.

Neither seems to work, I get the following error:
`[vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to resolve import "roughjs/bin/rough" from "node_modules/excalidraw-gp/packages/excalidraw/renderer/renderElement.ts?v=38f63b61"

tl; dr. Bit of advise: reduce the size of your question three- or four-fold. There's a lot of clutter here.

@YSC thanks for the advice, is this edit any better? Have some advice?

it's better, upvoted your question in hope it will help attract a knowledgeable peer
